# How to compare two lines in different files and output the same position in the other line in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I have two files and I want the output like below. Please help by providing me with a TCL script.

File1:

```
Name1: F * F F F
Name2: F F *
Name3: F F F F
```

File2:

```
Name1: AA, BB, CC, DD, EE,
Name2: AA, BB, CC,
Name3: AA, BB, CC, DD,
```

Output1:

```
Name1
  AA - FAIL
  BB - *
  CC - FAIL
  <cont>
Name2
  AA - FAIL
  BB - FAIL
  CC - *
  <cont>
```

Output2:

```
Name1
  FAIL - AA CC DD EE
  *    - BB
Name2
  FAIL - AA BB
  *    - CC
Name3
  FAIL - AA BB CC DD
```

Comment: Did you try to write some lines of code?

Comment: Yes, I get lists from FILE1 and FILE2 now my problem is how to get the output like the above.

Comment: Actually its a long code before I get that information for FILE1 and FILE2, the problem is the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following tested on `tclsh8.5`

```
set fd1 [open "input_file_1.txt" r]
set fd2 [open "input_file_2.txt" r]
set opfd [open "output_file.txt" w]

while {[gets $fd1 line] > 0 && [gets $fd2 line2] > 0} {
    set line1 [split $line ":"]
    set line2 [split $line2 ":"]
    puts $opfd [lindex $line1 0]

    set last_part_1 [string trim [lindex $line1 1] " "]
    set last_part_2 [string trim [lindex $line2 1] " "]

    set space_split [split $last_part_1 " "]
    set comma_split [split $last_part_2 ","]

    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $space_split]} {incr i} {
        puts $opfd "[string trim [lindex $comma_split $i] " "] = [string trim [lindex $space_split $i] " "]"
    }
}

close $fd1
close $fd2
close $opfd
```

There will be file named as `output_file.txt` created inside current directory which contains your output.

Comment: Dude we are not code writer for your homework.. at least play with the given code. Try something by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
package require fileutil

proc getInput filename {
    set contents [string trim [::fileutil::cat $filename]]
    set rows [split $contents \n]
    concat {*}[lmap item $rows {
        split $item :
    }]
}

set d1 [string map {F Fail} [getInput file1.txt]]
set d2 [string map {, {}} [getInput file2.txt]]
dict for {key values} $d1 {
    puts $key
    foreach v1 $values v2 [dict get $d2 $key] {
        puts "  $v2 - $v1"
    }
}
```

This works by recognizing the dictionary-like structure of the data files. If every piece of data is a word without spaces, this version of `getInput` will coerce the contents of each file to a usable `dict`. From there, it's just a matter of replacing the `F` strings with `Fail` strings and removing the commas, and then doing dictionary iteration over either one of the `dict`s and pulling in the corresponding values from the other one.

If the values in the second file may contain spaces, `getInput` should look like this:

```
proc getInput filename {
    set contents [string trim [::fileutil::cat $filename]]
    set rows [split $contents \n]
    set res {}
    foreach item $rows {
        lassign [split $item :] key values
        if {[string match *,* $values]} {
            set values [split [string trimright $values {, }] ,]
        }
        lappend res $key $values
    }
    return $res
}
```

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)